# What other context was Accelerated Projection-Based Consensus used?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

In the paper titled "Distributed Solution of Large-Scale Linear Systems via Accelerated Projection-Based Consensus" [link](https://azizan.mit.edu/papers/APC.pdf), the authors introduced a novel algorithm aimed at solving linear equations efficiently.

I recall that there was a similar algorithm developed some years ago, possibly originating from the field of Domain Decomposition. It would be interesting to find the compare and contrast of the proposed algorithm from the past.

I'm curious if anyone is familiar with this specific approach and could provide more information or insights regarding the method from Domain Decomposition.